# Shallow predicate to square each number in the list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to want to create a shallow predicate called say square to square each number in the list
example :

```
e.g. ?-square([a,[[3]],b,4,c(5),8],X).
       X=[a,[[3]],b,16,c(5),64]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial.

```
sq(X) :-
    number(X) -> X2 is X*X ; X2 = X.

square(List, Squared) :-
    maplist(sq, List, Squared).
```

But note that `square([X], X2), X=2` will not have the desired effect.

Comment: Can you guide me without using map list please

Comment: I want to do it recursive without using map list